# React/Redux: TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to update my state (list of users) with the edited fields of a certain user (`firstName`, `lastName`, `email`). The idea is whenever the user changes the value of an input in the form, a creator action is triggered to update the user object in the state with the new values. Below is my pieces of code:

In my `reducers.js`:

```
case actionCreators.changeUserValues.getType():
return {
...state,
usersList: [
  ...state.usersList.map((user) => {
    if (user.username === action.payload.username) {
      return {
        ...user,
        [action.payload.name]: action.payload.value,
      };
    }
    return user;
  }),
],
editButtonDisabled: false,
submitButtonDisabled: true,
selectedUserProfile: {
  userObject: {
    ...state.selectedUserProfile.userObject,
    [action.payload.name]: action.payload.value,
  },
},
};
```

In the `actionCreators.js` file:

```
const changeUserValues = createAction(CHANGE_USER_VALUES, userData => userData);

const onValueChange = event => (dispatch, getState) => {
  const { value, name } = event.target;
  const { username } = getState().selectedUserProfile.username;
  return dispatch(changeUserValues({ name, value, username }));
};
```

In my Containter:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  // some stuff
  onValueChange: () => dispatch(actionCreators.onValueChange()),
});
```

To test my code, I edit the form and I get this error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined` in the `onValueChange()` actionCreator code. I don't know how to pasS/capture the `event` (as I'm trying to 'redux' [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components))

Answer (score 2):

You are not passing in the event to your reducer

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  // some stuff
  onValueChange: (event) => dispatch(actionCreators.onValueChange(event)),
});
```

For a more complete answer... when you are using the input value just pass the event. As long as the mapDispatchToProps has the value in there as well it should make it all the way to your action/reducer.

`<input onChange={e=>this.props.onValueChange(e)} />`

Comment: Note that the `mapDispatch` usage can be simplified by using the "object shorthand" passing an object of action creators directly to `connect`.  In this case, it could probably be `export default connect(mapState, actionCreators)(MyComponent)`.

Comment: It didn't solve the issue when I passed it. Thanks for the correction though.

Comment: @occulti The event is still undefined in the action after adding the event in the call? How are you handling the onChange for the inputs?